# Data Format for Spark Mllib Recommender System

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following data format of a user-item matrix.

```
recommende_sct.head(1):

[Row(TRANS=353,  Bob Iger: How Do Companies Foster Innovation and Sustain Relevance=0,  “I Will What I Want” - Misty Copeland=0, "On the Lot" with Disney Producers=0, "Your Brain is Good at Inclusion...Except When it's Not" with Dr. Steve Robbins=0, (please do not use) WDW_ER-Leaders of Minors=0, 1. EAS Project Lifecycle Process Flow=0, 10 Life Lessons from Star Wars=0, 10 Simple Steps to Exceptional Daily Productivity=0, 10 Steps to Effective Listening=0, 10 Tips for Better Business Writing=0, 10 Tips for Effective Performance Reviews: You Can Improve the Positive Impact of Your Performance Reviews =0, 10 Tips for Tackling the Toughest Workplace Conflicts=0, 10 Tips to Help You Ace a Media Interview=0, 10550=0, 10873=0,
```

Basically each row is for a user and each column is the item name. Column names are the items name which are string and column value is either 1 or 0. It's a binary preference matrix.

Now I read the docs of Spark Mllib collaborative filtering algorithm and it appears they want the format to be of something like

(user, product, rating).

I am not sure what is that format and so having difficult to covert my format to their format before I could use Spark algo.

Could someone please help here?

Comment: You did not provide any links. But it's probably the following: a list of triplets (user, product, rating) where user and product are id's / integers. This is implicitly a sparse representation (only nonzero ratings are stored) and very common. If this is needed within some python-code it's probably a list of lists or a numpy-array of shape [n_samples, 3].

Comment: Here is the link 

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html

I am not sure how each row in this representation is supposed to look like?. I know in the original paper for collaborative filtering the format is same which I have currently User-Item matrix. But not sure the format of spark

Comment: It's described exactly in your link. Under the python tag. Your data is a list/iterable of Ratings: ```data=[Ratingobj, Ratingobj, ...]```, where a Ratingobj is described [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/mllib/recommendation.html). If you got a matrix (user-item); you need to convert the users to ids in range(0,n), the items to ids in range(0,m) (actually: maybe not needed, but i recommend it) and then create one Ratingobj for each entry which is nonzero = observed in this matrix. It's really basic!